# How to use Google Cloud HSM with jca api?

Tags: hsm

we have tested AWS HMS using jca api, just wanted to know if we can also use Google Cloud HSM with jca api ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no official JCA provider for Google Cloud HSM yet, see:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/9377

There is a partial implementation in the [Jsign](https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/) project (disclaimer: I'm the author) that supports signing only. Usage looks like this:

```
String keyring = "projects/first-rain-123/locations/global/keyRings/mykeyring";
SigningService service = new GoogleCloudSigningService(keyring, token, null);
Provider provider = new SigningServiceJcaProvider(service);

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("GOOGLECLOUD", provider);
keystore.load(null, "".toCharArray());

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, null);

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", provider);
sig.initSign(key);
sig.update(data);
byte[] signature = sig.sign();
```